# Android Emulator Error "emulator: ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting"

Tags: android, android-emulator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emulator problem in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740834/emulator-problem-in-android)

emulator: ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting

most of the time i face this problem..I restart Eclipse even..and restart emulator also..but still problem remain as it is. Why ?

Comment: This has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740834/emulator-problem-in-android).

Answer (score 18):

Problem : emulator: ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. 
Solution:
Delete following folders:
C:\Users\%UserName%.android\avd\AVD2.1.avd\cache.img.lock
C:\Users\%UserName%.android\avd\AVD2.1.avd\userdata-qemu.img.lock

Answer (score 6):

In your **Android SDK and AVD Manager** (under the Window menu if you cannot find it), launch the emulator by clicking the **Start** button. On the next screen tick the **Wipe User Data** box then click **Launch**.