# Eclipse (with adt) won't see/recognize a running avd

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt

I have been trying this for a week or so now.

I have followed the tutorial to get hello android working but while an AVD starts the program doesn't run.

I am running Windows 7 64 bit with eclipse 3.5.2 running adt 0.9.9 and SDK r7.

the sdk is installed in C:\android-sdk-windows
eclipse is installed in C:\eclipse

What i can do:

- create an AVD (through console and the manager)
- i can compile the code
- Run my code (on automatic it will start an avd)

Bad stuff that happens

- when i run my code on manual my running avd does not appear
- when i run on automatic with my avd already started i get the error --> emulator: ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting

what i have tried

- using the correct version of eclipse (i started on 3.6)
- reinstalling everything (inclusind deleting my work space)
- starting the avd with wipe user data
- changing the port for DDMS from 8600 to 8200 (suggested on another post)
- adding the path to sdk tools to environment variables
- SDK location in eclipse -> preferences -> andorid is C:\android-sdk-windows

Beginning to pulll my hair out.

Can anyone help

Comment: are you running 64 bit eclipse or 64 bit java

Comment: 64 bit eclipse with JDK 64 bit

Comment: So you can create an AVD, hit start and run the AVD? Then when you go to run your app on the device it can't find it?

Do you have the right target/platform? By that I mean is your app compiled with Android 1.6 and the AVD is at least 1.6 or higher?

Comment: min sdk in my app is 2 which i believe relates to 1.1 my avd is 1.5. I believe it is ok to go this way but not theother way i.e. run a 1.5 app on 1.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check here

[Emulator problem in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740834/emulator-problem-in-android)

I think I had the same problem before. Its something to do with the folder or image file eclipse creates. It gets corrupted and you have to manually delete it or something like that.

Look at the link, there are multiple solutions to your problem. See which one works.

Comment: Thank-you for taking the time-out to point out this problem much appreciated

Comment: Launching the avd through eclipse initially doesn't work but running "adb kill-server && adb start-server" after avd load seems to do the trick

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem on windows for my galaxy samsung device .. installing [samsung kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) solve the problem for me.