# Running android project in an already running AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I have installed Android SDK 4. I am trying to run Notepad application given in the sample projects. When i try to run the project its starting new AVD. But its not loading, its just hangs in the `ANDROID` screen. It does not even show the home screen.

If i start the AVD manually from AVD manager. The emulator starts successfully. But i am not able to run the `Notepad` project in the already running emulator. When i run the project its just starting a new emulator and shows the Loading Screen and stays still.

What could be the issue!

Comment: When you run the AVD by hand, does `adb` recognize it when it's fully launched? Use `adb devices` from the command line, if the list is empty something is fishy. If it's not there you can try to restart adb by calling `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server` and see if the device appears then. You can find the `adb` command in your `ANDROID_SDK/platform-tools` folder, in case its not in your PATH already.

Comment: check here for some other solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973446/eclipse-with-adt-wont-see-recognise-a-runnving-avd

Answer (score 3):

You can to go `Run Configurations` (by clicking the arrow beside the Run button in Eclipse), then in the `Target` tab change the `Deployment Target Selection Mode` to `Manual`. Then when you run the project Eclipse will show you a list of running emulators from which you can choose which emulator you want to run the project in.

Edit: Make sure your projects min-sdk version is lower than or equal to the avd's android api level

Comment: I tried that one too. I changed to manual mode. When running the app its not showing the already running avd in the list.