# Error while running the project in android(eclipse)

Tags: android

sir i have got an error while running my project in ecclipse. The error is:

***([2010-12-23 10:42:26 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting)***

kindly you please help me to solve this error.

thanks.

Comment: refer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740834/emulator-problem-in-android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found a way of avoiding getting this issue, but you can do this to solve quickly:

Remove:

```
C:/Users/%user_name%/.android/avd/%name_of_avd%/cache.img.lock
C:/Users/%user_name%/.android/avd/%name_of_avd%/userdata-qemu.img.lock
```

You won't need to restart the emulator.

Comment: but still it gives an warning that: ([2010-12-23 12:45:25 - helloandroid.project] ActivityManager: Warning: Activity not started, its current task has been brought to the front
)

Comment: @user552027 do one thing: Just restart your Emulator and run the application again.

Comment: can you explain me why we use this code while programing on androidpackage hello.com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Helloworld extends Activity {