# AVD emulator has is disconnected

Tags: android, connection, android-virtual-device

I created avd and start it. Emulator is always disconnected as shown here https://www.dropbox.com/s/wymyn04aglc039q/disconnected.PNG?dl=0

I have wi-fi internet connection on my laptop. I already tried to use such methods as:
1) restart avd, eclipse or smth
2) start avd as "emulator -avd {avd_name} -dns-server {dns_name}"
3) Windows Firewall turned off
4) disable any other network adapters (only wireless one able)

and all of it useless for me(

emulator is always online, but still disconnected https://www.dropbox.com/s/oe6twir4njr1mrh/disconnected2.PNG?dl=0

Please, help!

Comment: did you check the WIFI setting in emulator.

Comment: where are those settings? i can't find them

Comment: In Emulator Go to Settings --> More.. --> Mobile Networks --> Data Enabled.Check Data is enabled or not.

Comment: in settings i found only: brightness, airplane mode, bluetooth, always-on screen, power off, restart, reset, change watch face, About. That is all.

Comment: Can you add the settings screen shot.

Comment: settings screen https://www.dropbox.com/s/oz2s8vzkfworwu5/settings.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Did you create an application for android wear or Mobile,Tab? If you develop application for Mobile and tab means change the emulator OS from 4.4W to 4.4.If interest in use other emulator use [Genymotion emulator](http://www.genymotion.com/) its faster than android emulator to run and debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Reset adb

[image]

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21825603/2176734

or try This

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6013668/2176734

Comment: adb connect localhost:5555 ------

connected to localhost:5555

it's ok, i guess

Comment: emulator is always online, but still disconnected https://www.dropbox.com/s/oe6twir4njr1mrh/disconnected2.PNG?dl=0